# Skinny fat - What running/hiking routine or tips would you recommend?

Tags: running, weight-loss, running-training-plan

**Background:**

Age: 34

Height: 167cm

Weight: 76kg

Waist : 96 cm(38 inches)

Average running pace : 7 min 17 secs/km

Average distance : 4 km.

I lead a rather inactive lifestyle, mostly keeping indoors over the last 8-10 months. Being in a new job, I found it tough to balance work with personal time, though now I am more settled. I realised that the maxim, *life's a marathon and not a sprint* is true. Therefore, I am sticking to a routine now by starting early and winding up the day at 5.30 pm, so I can go for 1-1.5 hours of running and studies.

I have an extreme skinny-fat physique, with lots of visceral fat, but skinny hands and feet. It has just slowly crept on.

Food-habits. Regular 3 meals a day, Asian Indian. Oatmeals/Muesli(roasted) for breakfast.

**Activities I enjoy**

I enjoy hiking and love climbing(non-technical). I went on a 100 km cycling day trip this year. I am fond of running and I have started with a modest goal running 4 km every day. I jog(slow-run) on flats on one day, and on the next I do 10-12 repeats of a sprint on a small stretch on a hill (34m elevation)nearby to home. I found I really enjoy hill climbing, my legs feel rejuvenated after this, unlike slow running on flats, where I experience lactate build-up and have to break my run.

I am not much of a gymnasium guy.

**Goals:**

Over the course of the next year, my goal is to be well-toned, develop some core strength and have a flat stomach, lose about 15-16 kgs of weight.

What running/hill climbing/hiking training routine, schedule or tips would you recommend?

Comment: I recommend a good nutrition plan and consistency! However, I'm not a runner, winded myself walking my dog yesterday, so I hope someone can provide you with better training advice.

Comment: Skinny fat isn't really about fat. Rather it is about lack of muscle. Strength training should be given more importance than plain cardio in your case.